# How to share enviroment variables in docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I´m new to docker and I´m having lots of troubles to make it start. I´m making an asp.net core 1.0.1 application user docker container tools for visual studio 2017. I have the following env.file in the same root as the compose file  with this values:

```
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

and this docker compose yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  haproxy:
    image: eeacms/haproxy
    links:
      - webapplication3
    ports:
     - "80:80"   
  webapplication3:
    image: webapplication3
    enviroment:
      - REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - redis
    ports:
     - "80"
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
     - ${REDIS_PORT}
```

I want to know the redis port I have to connect to from my Asp.net core app. As far as I know, the only way to do it is using env variables, and since I don´t want to copy paste the port everywhere I´d like to use the .env file style. Anyway this is not working saying:

```
Unsupported config option for services.webapplication3:'enviroment'
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a letter "n" in a word `environment`.

Comment: Thanks both, just misspelled the "n". Everything is working fine now!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the env_file option:

```
version: '2'

services:
  haproxy:
    image: eeacms/haproxy
    links:
      - webapplication3
    ports:
     - "80:80"   
  webapplication3:
    image: webapplication3
    env_file:
      - env.file
    environment:
      - REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - redis
    ports:
     - "80"
  redis:
    image: redis
    env_file:
      - env.file
    ports:
     - ${REDIS_PORT}
```

Take a look at https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/ for more info.